# Google Chart API: Change color on hovering legend

Tags: javascript, css, svg, google-api, google-visualization

So I have a [ColumnChart](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/columnchart) and one of the built-in functionality is that you can hover over an item (so called category) in the legend of the chart and you get some highlight-border around the corresponding columns in the chart.

Now I have many columns and categories in my chart and a highlighted series/category is very hard to see, because the default behavior just shows a 1px gray border around the columns. My columns are only a few pixels width and I still need to differentiate 10 different categories (=colors). So picking only very light colors (where the border would be easy to spot) is no option. I've found no way of changing:

1. The style of the highlight-border (primarily the color) **or**
2. The color of the columns (fill color) when their respective category is selected in the legend.

Is there some property I can pass to the `draw()` call of my chart to change the highlighting? Do I have to manually override some events/methods?

Help is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the past I used some CSS hacks to change some properties of the generated SVG (path, rect, etc...)
you can play around with advanced selectors and maybe you'll be able to achieve you what you want. 
I created a very quick and buggy example, but maybe it will point you on the right direction.

For example:

```
div.google_chart svg g g g g rect { 
            stroke-width:0px; fill:red; 
            }
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Oh my god it actually works. Thank you so much. Your code highlights the currently selected column, where you hover over. To get an entire series (hover over the legend) the following code will do:  `div.google_chart svg g g g g rect {
    stroke-width:0px;
    fill:red;
}` - This navigates down the SVG tree. Looks awesome! Maybe update your answer, so it can be spotted right away. And again: thank you!

Comment: Cool Peter! Glad you managed to find the correct CSS! I updated my answer, like you said, to be spotted right away, and deleted the jsfiddle link, that somehow it was not the correct one. Glad I could help! cheers

Comment: Thank you CMoreira, you really helped me. It is perfect, it saved me a lot of time.

Comment: While this is a great solution I want to point out that to support IE 8 and before, you need to do some extra work to also catch the VML it generates instead of SVG.

Comment: god bless you!!